# Open a specific tab in a css based tabstructure

Tags: javascript, php, css, tabs

can someone please help me out here?

I have a css based tabstructure.
The first tab is default when page is loaded.

I would like to have a link from an other page direct to the page with the tabs and
directly open the non-default tab. For example the second tab (id: tabl2 ).
Some help is very much appreciated.

Link:  http://www.mijncambodja.nl/?link=cambodja-phnom-penh

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li>
<input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
<label for="tab1">Algemeen</label>
<div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">content tab 1
</div>
</li>

<li>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
<label for="tab2">Bezienswaardigheden</label>
<div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">content tab 2
</div>
</li>

<li>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
<label for="tab3">Hotels</label>
<div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">content tab 3
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Javascript to detect which tab is loaded. To do that, you have to send the tab to the URL: tab.html#2. Then in javascript you use: location.hash to detect which tab is loaded.

```
// displaying the element with ID "tab-content2" if #2
var hash = location.hash.substring(1);
document.getElementById('tab-content' + hash).style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Edit your code with your new code (javascript and HTML).

Comment: I inserted an external link: mijncambodja.nl/?link=cambodja-phnom-penh#tab2 and <li> <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab_tab2"> <label for="tab2">Bezienswaardigheden</label> <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">content tab 2 </div> </li> and the javascript part but it still doesn`t work. Should it have to do with my url? : ?link=

Comment: The ID "tab_tab2" should be on the div. If the ID of your div is "tab-content3", then just adapt the javascript code. I just edited.

Comment: Don't forget to indicate the answer as approved so that users can see that your problem is solved.